Clarification regarding using big-O/big-oh notation in a denominator
Given
$$ f(x) = 1/(1 + O(x)) \quad\text{as}\quad x\rightarrow 0, $$
how do we interpret the right-hand expression properly?
Do we say that for sufficiently small $x$ that $f(x) \le 1/(1 + C|x|)$ or that $f(x) \le 1/(1 - C|x|)$ for some positive constant $C$? Which is the correct interpretation?
My confusion comes from the fact that the former interpretation gives a stronger inequality, and it's not clear which one should be employed.

$O(x)$ represents an unspecified function $g(x)$ about which we know precisely one thing—that $g(x)/x$ is bounded (near $x=0$ in this case). Let's say that $|g(x)/x| \le M$. It follows that
$$
\frac1{1+Mx} \le f(x) = \frac1{1+g(x)} \le \frac1{1-Mx}
$$
when $x$ is sufficiently near $0$.
Exercise: show that this turns out to be equivalent to $f(x) = 1+O(x)$.
